# PHP how to optimize writing to file in this situation

Tags: php, mysql, csv

To better explain you my situation I will both describe it and supply corresponding **pseudo-code(sort of)**. I'm in a dilemma and need some help.

So I have this function which is called upon consecutively and frequently. In the function I have a *for* loop which executes a variable number of times, based on supplied data. In that *for* loop there is an array which gets populated with all of that data. Still in the function, when the *for* loop ends, the array gets written into a CSV file. And then execution stops. However as I mentioned the function gets called frequently one call after the other, this results in repeated steps of populating the array in the loop and then writing into the file. The pseudocode illustrates this situation better(not my actual code, just mockup):

```
-call function stuff n times
               //Paragraph2 solution? -- global array declaration here ?

  function stuff
  {

    for loop(conditions)
    {
     array <= data
    }

    array => file   // Paragraph2 solution? -- Global array <= loop arrays 
 }

         // Paragraph2 solution? -- Global array => write to file
```

This works just fine. The problem lies in the speed of writing to the file. I think it is impaired because of all the little arrays that constantly get written into the file. I want to make all these arrays in the *for* loop to write their data into a global array outside the loop so that I can just take this one array with all the data and insert it in the CSV file, so I would have just one transaction to the file instead of the countless transactions that I had before. So, is this what I thought of possible, is it correct, or is there a better way of doing this? And can you please supply usable code in you answer. Thank You.

Comment: Your thinking is flawed to an extent because you're assuming that physical disk writes correspond with the write statements in your code; but most modern operating systems cache file changes and write them in blocks rather than individually

Comment: Are you opening and closing the file each time through the loop?  What file I/O functions are you using?  Why don't you post your actual code instead of pseudocode?

Comment: I'm using the fputcsv function for writing to a csv file. And the code is rather long and I just need help with this logic.

Comment: are you accumulating into an array just so you can re output it or is there array based processing occurring that is requiring you buffer the file like this?

Comment: There is no array based processing, I just want to make the arrays in the loop into one single array so that I can open the file stream just once, and not n times for every single array in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use a global array inside the function

```
$stuff = array();

function add_stuff($new_stuff)
{
    global $stuff;

    $stuff[] = $new_stuff;
}

add_stuff("hello");
add_stuff("world");

print_r($stuff);
```

the output should be:

```
Array
(
  [0] => hello
  [1] => world
)
```